# Using Python Parser in ArcGIS Pro Field Calculator?

Tags: field-calculator, arcgis-pro, python-parser

I am having a problem in migrating from Vbscript to Python for ArcGIS Pro.

> Building 5, Street 6

What is wrong in this expression?

```
"{}:{}:{}:{}:{}:{}".format("Building ",!Building_Number!," , ",!Street_Type!), " " ,!Street_Number!
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First glance - it looks like your parentheses in the wrong place:

```
"{}:{}:{}:{}:{}:{}".format("Building ",!Building_Number!," , ",!Street_Type!, " " ,!Street_Number!)
```

Comment: This would return a string of values separated by colons.

Answer (score 2):

Try Code Block:

```
def bs(bnumber, stype):
    return "Building {0}, Street {1}".format(bnumber,stype)
```

Call with:

```
bs(!Building_number!,!Street_Type!)
```